# Error #1006: value is not a function. made a function through movieclip.Function and call it in eventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3

I got piece of code:

```
gameholder.addChild(crocodile);
crocodile.Function = this["croccheck"];
crocodile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,animalclick);
private function animalclick(evt:Event):void
    {
        if(!evt.currentTarget.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,evt.currentTarget.Function))
        {
            evt.currentTarget.name.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,evt.currentTarget.Function);
        }
    }
private function croccheck(evt:Event):void
    {
        if(evt.currentTarget.currentLabel == Info.ANIMALS_READY)
        {
            evt.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay(Info.ANIMALS_ACT + "1");
            evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,evt.currentTarget.Function);
        }
    }
```

Even i got this error

TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
    at main/animalclick()

it still work fine but i wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener()` returns void, and you have there in `animalClick` a check of its return value. This apparently resolves to false, thus the second `addEventListener` call is made, vs `name` property, which is in turn a `String`, thus does not have `addEventListener` as a function. So, you should clean up your `animalClick` function to this:

```
private function animalclick(evt:Event):void
{
    if(evt.currentTarget.Function)
    {
        evt.currentTarget.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,evt.currentTarget.Function);
    }
}
```

Here you are checking if there's any `Function` that you can add, if yes, then add, if no, then skip.